# Ruby - converting a hashtag to actual word(s) ? (#contentmarketing => content marketing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, twitter

Hashtags sometimes combine two or more words, such as:

```
content marketing => #contentmarketing
```

If I have a bunch of hashtags assigned to an article, and the word is in that article, i.e. `content marketing`. How can I take that hash tag, and detect the word(s) that make up the hashtag?

If the hashtag is a single word, it's trivial: simply look for that word in the article. But, what if the hash tag is two or more words? I could simply split the hashtag in all possible indices and check if the two words produced were in the article.

So for `#contentmarketing`, I'd check for the words:

- c ontentmarketing
- co ntentmarketing
- con tentmarketing
- ...
- content marketing <= THIS IS THE ANSWER!
- ...

However, this fails if there are three or more words in the hashtags, unless I split it recursively but that seems very inelegant.

Again, this is assuming the words in the hash tag are in the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex with an optional space between each character to do this:

```
your_article =~ /#{hashtag.chars.to_a.join(' ?')}/
```

Comment: Dang, that was fast.. and elegant... and simple.

Comment: Should it be /#{hashtag.chars.to_a.join(' ?')}/ though?

Comment: @HenleyChiu: yup - updated

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible solutions depending on the requirements for the hashtags:

1. Assuming hashtags must be made up of words and can't be non-words like "#abfgtest":

   ```
   Do the test similar to your answer above but only test the first part of the string. If the test fails then add another character and try again until you have a word. Then repeat this process on the remaining string until you have found each word. So using your example it would first test:

   - c
   - co
   - ...
   - content <- Found a word, start over with rest 
   - m
   - ma
   - ...
   - marketing <- Found a word, no more string so exit
   ```
2. If you can have garbage, then you will need to do the same thing as option 1. with an additional step. Whenever you reach the end of the string without finding a word, go back to the beginning + 1. Using the `#abfgtest` example, first you'd run the above function on "abfgtest", then "bfgtest", then "fgtest", etc.